# How do I pass an url as parameter in router.get() method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I am trying to pass an url http://localhost:3000/new/https://www.example.com to `router.get('/new/:url', function..)` But instead of getting the url (https://www.example.com) in `req.params.url`, this link http://localhost:3000/new/https://www.example.com leads to 404 Not Found error. Although other paramters works fine eg. http://localhost:3000/new/www.example.com

code:

```
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/new/:url', function(req, res...);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you are forgetting to encode your URL components, it should be: `http://localhost:3000/new/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com`

Comment: @JuanMendes thanks for your response..But user won't encode the url rather I've handle it in my code.

Comment: Are users typing that URL directly?

Comment: yes, actually code is part of an url-shortener application. so user types the url to get the shortened url back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to append normal unencoded URL as query param, it leads to new path

*http://localhost:3000/new/https://www.example.com* becomes an entirely new URl which may not be available in your server

One way to pass the URL is to encode as @Juan Mendes mentioned
*http://localhost:3000/new/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com*

However, there is a work around, use wildcard such as **"/new/*"** . Boom